# How to fix 'TypeError: (images || []).forEach is not a function'

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, botframework

Within Node.js (MS Bot Framework is being used), I'm trying to iterate over an array containing multiple objects that was returned by `fetch()`. **It does one iteration and then throws an error.**

I did already take node-fetch out of the equation and used a static array of my objects. I also tried converting to an array. Still the same result: `TypeError: (images || []).forEach is not a function` after the first iteration went perfectly well.

This is what it looks like at the moment (shortened object values for readability):

```
// exact copy of what fetch returns
let test = [
    {
        title: 'Power BI Desktop—Interactive Reports | Microsoft Power BI',
        link: 'https://support.office.com/',
        description: 'Create interactive reports with data',
        thumbnail: 'https://powerbi.microsoft.com/'
    }, {
        title: 'What is Power BI administration? - Power BI',
        link: 'https://support.office.com/',
        description: 'Learn about the configuration of Power BI ',
        thumbnail: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/'
    }, {
        title: 'Add a PowerBI tab to Teams',
        link: 'https://support.office.com/',
        description: 'You can add a new or existing PowerBI',
        thumbnail: 'https://support.office.com/'
    }
];

let cardContent = [];
test.forEach(element => {
    logger.debug('working on: %j', element);
    let card = CardFactory.heroCard(
        element.title,
        element.description,
        element.thumbnail,
        [element.link],
        ['Open Item']
    );
    cardContent.push(card);
});
```

Just for reference, here is part of my fetch function:

```
return fetch(url + question)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(jsonResponse => {
        return jsonResponse;
    })
```

I really don't know what else to try now. The exact same setup worked on a legacy version of my application - only with `axios` but I tried that as well.

Comment: `(images || []).forEach` is not anywhere in the code you posted...?

Comment: If that's the error you get, evidently images is truthy but not an array. Maybe consider https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: What fetch function are you talking of? You're not using promises anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Exactly, which is why I'm completely stumped as to where that error comes from. I've dug a bit deeper into the source of Bot Framework and it appears to be a bug in their `CardFactory`.

Comment: **Cause found:** The documentation states you can send image URLs as a string. However, they have to be in an array: `(images || []).forEach((img: (CardImage | string))`. That is where the error came from. Sadly, bot frameworks documentation is lackluster in places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run your code and it works - this mean that `test` array doesn't contains what do you think it contains (probably it contains Promise returned by fetch() ). Use fetch with `await` keyword to get response and again use `await` to get json (something like code below - I write it form head)

```
async function load(url, question) {
    ...
    return await (await fetch(url + question)).json()
}

...
test = await load(url, question) // this call shoud be also inside async function
```

Comment: Likely, `test` (or `images` in your production code) is defined but not an array.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out there is an error in the MS Bot Framework documentation which stated you could send image URLs as a simple string while they actually have to be within an array.
Would you say it is better practise to use `await` even before fetch()? I've never done so (and didn't see it anywhere before) and it works just fine. Everything else is using `await`, I just never thought of using it before fetch() within an async function.

Comment: In my pinion await is good to deal witch promises (e.g. returned by fetch()).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to tell with certainty why `(images || []).forEach` is not a function without knowing where/how `images` is defined, but I'm going to hazard a guess and say `images` *exists*, and is an object instead of an array.

Try executing

```
const images = {};
images.forEach(image => console.log(image))
```

And you'll see the same result, `Uncaught TypeError: images.forEach is not a function`.

Maybe it is the images.data field within the object that you want to run `forEach` on.